# Multilevel Select attribute in custom entities

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

In the Sales Literature entity, there is a Subject attribute that acts like a "multilevel" select. Technically this is a Lookup. Is there a way to have similar multilevel select boxes in other entities?

[image: multilevel select box]

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Subject is a special entity that comes automatically with the platform for organizing the cases (incidents) or KB articles. Everyone like to have that taxonomy like custom attribute but its not achievable.

But you can use that same Subject entity to create a lookup attribute in any custom entity. Its going to be the same entries everywhere.

Go to Settings - Service Management - Subjects, to customize the taxonomy entries. Create a new lookup attribute in custom entity & add to the form.

[image]

[image]

[image]